# How to have my own App folder for images that can be accessed through Photo gallery official iOS (Delphi/Firemonkey)

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

I'm developing an App that can create their own images. That images I want to save to an own and local folder (like WhatsApp and others App), but I need that local folder can be accessed from Photos official iOS app (like WhatsApp, DJI...).

Please, how I can create my own folder to save and get images from my App, and that folder can be accessed from gallery of iOS?

It is probably not very difficult because this method is used by many applications, but I have been looking for 5 days and I can not find anything.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can mix this both solution on a class function with if def Android or iOS.

On iOS you need to add a entry for permission `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription`

And save photo to album like this :

```
if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXPhotoLibrary, Service) then
     Service.AddImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageMain.Bitmap);
```

I know you are only interessed by iOS but I use too this Android solution where I get the last DCIM path (internal/external) with this code :

```
function GetDCIMPath: string;
const
  CST_DCIM_PATH = '/DCIM/';
var
  ContentResolver: JContentResolver;
  Cursor: JCursor;
  Path: string;
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := '';

  ContentResolver := TAndroidHelper.ContentResolver;
  Cursor := ContentResolver.query(TJImages_Media.JavaClass.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, nil, nil, nil, StringToJString('datetaken DESC'));

  try
    if Assigned(Cursor) then
    begin
      Cursor.moveToFirst;

      // can be replace with a repeat until
      while not Result.ToUpper.Contains(CST_DCIM_PATH) do
      begin
        i := Cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJString('_data'));
        if i <> -1 then
          Result := JStringToString(Cursor.getString(i));

        if not Cursor.moveToNext then
          Break;
      end;
      // ex : /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/FolderName/LastPicture.png 
      if Result.ToUpper.Contains(CST_DCIM_PATH) then
        Result := Copy(Result, 0, Result.IndexOf(CST_DCIM_PATH) + CST_DCIM_PATH.Length);
    end;
  finally
    Cursor.close;
  end;
end;
```

Thats a fast code, you can change the string parameter with the good const.
And to save your image :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Path : string;
  Folder: string;
begin
  Path   := GetDCIMPath;
  Folder := TPath.Combine(Path, 'MyAppFolder');

  if not TDirectory.Exists(Folder) then
    TDirectory.CreateDirectory(Folder);

  // just a TImage for test
  Image1.Bitmap.SaveToFile(TPath.Combine(Folder, 'picture.jpg'));
end;
```

Dont forget too the permission to read/write on storage.

Comment: Thank you Bosshoss, but using IFMXPhotoLibrary you haven't control. My App need create 5 images, then need to load these images, modify it, and save again modified..., I can create first 5 images with IFMXPhotoLibrary, but I can't have control on name or format (iOS assign it automatically). Then, IFMXPhotoLibrary can't grant me to load or delete images.

Comment: I was think that creating my own gallery, I would can save, delete and edit images, but now I know that all must be in General (Camera Roll) folder. I need to save, delete and load images.